# Search column in sheet for value; if found copy first two column values and column header

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy-paste

I have no experience with VBA but I was asked at work to come up with a solution to this problem.
I have a sheet that has data like so:

**Name .....    Date Changed** ....... **01/01/13......   01/02/13........   01/03/13**

Joe         ............ 02/05/13.....................Late

The top date values are the date that the bill due and the date value   (1/05/13) would be the date that the bill changed.  I need to search each date column (1/1-1/3) and for the word "Late" if found I need to copy and paste the name and date changed and date due into another worksheet.   In this example I would copy the the values:

Joe........02/05/13.........01/01/13

Into another sheet.  I would appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use VBA for that. Use the INDEX and MATCH functions to lookup where Late falls.

Later on you can filter to only show the lines that do have late in the columns 1/1-1/3.

Adapt as you see fit but here is the basic idea.

Insert a column between "date changed" and 1/1/2013 and name it "Date Due" (that would be column c now).

If cell C2, enter `=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$F2,1,MATCH("Late",$D2:$F2,0)),"")`

Drag and drop in column C

[image: This is what it should look like]

Comment: I was about to offer the same answer... so i vote that one up! Keep It Simple is the rule

Comment: That's right. And getting better at VBA means knowing when to use it but also when NOT to use it!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  That was much simplier than I thought and worked perfectly.  I'm using the same solution to solve my next problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... This searches column "C" for the word "Late", and if it is there it copies the entire row and pastes it into a new worksheet, it will loop for all the data you have and paste all rows with late in the new worksheet. It doesn't do exactly what you need, but is a good starting point.

```
Dim j As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

For j = 2 To ws1.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).row
    If ws1.Cells(j, 2) = "late" Then ws1.Rows(j).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row + 1)
Next j
```